# How can I keep an AMQP connection open when using Ruby-Amqp?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ and [ruby-amqp](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp) with Rails. When a message is received by a controller I perform the following:

```
def create 
  AMQP.start("amqp://localhost:5672") do |connection|
    channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
    exchange = channel.direct("")
    exchange.publish("some msg", :routing_key => "some key")

    EventMachine.add_timer(2) do
      exchange.delete
      connection.close { EventMachine.stop }
    end
  end
end
```

1. Is there a way to keep the AMQP connection open so I don't have to call `start` every time a request comes in?

I assume that opening a connection to Rabbit MQ is inefficient, however I haven't found a way to pass a block of code to a persistant connection.

Comment: you are definitely right here opening a connection each time you want to send something is very inefficient.  Not familiar enough with ruby to suggest how to go about it though

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep AMQP connection open, try to set a global variable to keep connection unique.

```
def start_em
  EventMachine.run do
    $connection = AMQP.connect(CONNECTION_SETTING) unless $connection
    yield
  end
end

def publish(message, options = {})
  start_em {
    channel  = AMQP::Channel.new($connection)           
    exchange = channel.direct('')                          
    exchange.publish(message, {:routing_key => 'rails01'}.merge(options))
    EventMachine.add_timer(1) { exchange.delete }        
  }
end
```

And don't forget to delete channel after you pulish your message.